# Create a Wiki-Page Template and use it (Sharepoint Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template, wiki, wiki-pages

When I am on the homepage and click on the new button, a drop-down opens with the elements list, page, document libary, app and subwebsite.

I would like to know if I can **create templates for webpartsites** and **wiki pages**. This templates should be **visible** and **selectable** in this **drop-down-menu**.

How can I implement these requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, you cannot change the new menu in Home page. You may need to go to site pages library to add a wiki page or other page templates.

Comment: How do I embed a template in this menu of the site page library?